# Docker, .NET - multiple projects inside build context

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have multiple .NET projects inside a single folder. These projects have references on common projects located in the same folder.

Lets say I want to build images of API, Identity, API2. My dockerfile is generated by VSCode, so it does the following - restore nuget, copy .., then publish.

Instead of this, I want to build everything once, restore once and then publish to a separate containers in order to reduce the build time.

The project structure is following:

API.csproj
Identity.csproj
API2.csproj

BL1.csproj
BL2.csproj
BL3.csproj

I'm pretty sure it should be achievable by creating an image where everything was already built and then I would be able to create images for API, Identity, API2 based on this container.

Any ideas?

Comment: Build a cd/ci pipeline, or actions in github

Comment: I was wondering if you could create base Docker image so instead of FROM aspnet you can do FROM myBaseImage. See documentation here - https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

Comment: If you make sure your volumes are a `bind` mount, then each "build" output should be persisted in your local `/obj/`/`bin/` folders. So if you just create your dockerfiles you should find that the projects that require building should only be built once if .net respects incremental builds? :)